# Recommend PHP/MySQL CMS with paid/premium content support

Tags: php, wordpress, drupal, content-management-system, expressionengine

I am looking at some solutions for building a site with a mix of free and paid/premium content (no, it's not porn).

I gather that Drupal has the Premium plugin which supports this.  I'm also looking at Expression Engine, which seems to have some built in support for this, although Paypal is the only payment option.

I'm looking at aMember (http://www.amember.com/) which seems to be a user role package that supports this, supports lots of payment methods, and has plugins to tie in to both Expression Engine and Wordpress.

Frankly, I find Drupal very frustrating to work with, so I'm leaning towards EE or Worpress + aMember.   Am I missing any other good options?  Anyone have experience with any of these packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expression Engine is amazing, and there is tons of support on their forums. I'm sure someone has found a way to use more than just paypal with it, just ask on the forums there and see what they say. But I'd recommend EE

Answer (score 1):

Joomla has been a good CMS for such sites, as we can see social-networking, e-commerce, subscription website, news website, etc

Or maybe Data Life Engine (DLE) would suit you (not free)

Answer (score 0):

A second vote for EE here! The initial learning curve can feel a little steep, but it makes up for it with an extremely easy and intuitive templating system. But yeah, definitely check the forums and the EE wiki to see what other e-commerce and payment handler plugins/modules there are.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a vote for EE here. If you dig a little bit into the system,  you'll find the membership piece to allow for a wide range of functionality between many levels of users. Different groups users can be assigned different levels of access to viewing, and even publishing content.

Answer (score 0):

Well, If you use WordPress you can plenty options but I think the best membership plugin for wordpress is [CMS Members](http://wpwave.com/plugins/cms-members/).